# Why does it seem like so few of the songs from the Minecraft soundtrack ever actually play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I absolutely love the Minecraft soundtrack. However, it seems like that a very select few of the many songs that C418 has written and produced and released in the Minecraft - Volume A & B albums are ever actually played in the game.

Looking in the `.mnecraft/resources/music/` and `.minecraft/resources/newmusic` folders there are only a total of 14 songs (calm1.ogg, calm2.ogg, calm3.ogg, hal1.ogg, hal2.ogg, hal3.ogg, hal4.ogg, nuance1.ogg, nuance2.ogg, piano1.ogg, paino2.ogg, & piano3.ogg.)

Obviously, that explains the lack of variation in the soundtracks played. <s>but does anyone know why so much more music was written and not used?</s>

**Edit**:

Reading in the Minecraft Wiki ([Volume B](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_-_Volume_Beta), [Volume A](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_-_Volume_Alpha)), it appears that more music (from Volume B) *is* in fact included in the game, but is simply non-existent for me?

[image]

Does anyone know why I only have a select few that actually ever play or even exist for me?

Comment: This is kinda a "why did the devs do this" sort of question, which often don't work super well here. That said, I don't know a crapton about Minecraft, so it might be answered somewhere, I suppose.  Just don't be surprised if it gets labelled as unanswerable because we aren't (obviously) the Minecraft devs.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Fair enough. I was just curious and figured I'd post it here. Seeing as I've already received one down-vote and you commented with this I'll just delete the question.

Comment: I honestly have no idea if it is completely unanswerable or not, because I am not lying when I say I know nothing about Minecraft. Someone might know the answer (especially because your edit makes it seem like maybe something is going wrong for you specifically). I'd leave the question up for now, and see if someone more knowledgeable in the ways of cube shaped architecture has a better understanding.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Ah. I see. I'll leave it up for a bit longer. Hopefully that down-vote was a careless passerby down-vote and doesn't reflect everyone's opinion :P

Comment: Yeah, it's just one downvote, I'd not worry overmuch.

Comment: The way this is written, it sounds like a question that should be answered by the devs (and thus should maybe be closed here). Judging from the title however, if you want to get the music to play more frequently, that's what your question  should be focusing on, and that is something we can answer

Comment: @Robotnik Ah. Well, my initial question *was* why does the soundtrack play so rarely, but I sorta answered that on my own and in the process morphed it into the "Why don't I have these others and how do I fix it?" question like you mentioned. I'll try editing my question to make that more clear.

Comment: For the songs that do play, it's programmed in to be pseudorandom (some clips are litterally less likely to play than others within an event group) others play more or less based on your game play. Psychology shows that there are songs that play in the game that you've probably never realized were there due to when and why they play. As for the ones that actually don't play, it's because they opted (at which version I don't recall) to include the full sound track with the game. A soundtrack isn't always songs that are in the game (or movie) but just songs that fit it.

Comment: As fro rarity in terms of game play, there's a sound cllp that only plays on a full moon at night. An event that is already rare by design, and then only if you don't sleep the night away on it.

Comment: I have also Experienced this biased music being played. However back in 1.7.2 everything was fine. when I hear these music today I feel nostalgic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C418 has written a lot of Minecraft music, but only some of it was made to be **in** Minecraft. A significant minority of the tracks on the albums *Minecraft - Volume Alpha* and *Minecraft - Volume Beta* are not from the game and were created for the albums.

You have to admit, if C418 released *Minecraft - Volume Alpha* with only the tracks that were in the game at the time, it would be a disappointingly familiar album and unexciting news. Instead, he recorded more music available exclusively on that album, and made the album that much more worth buying. This is even [mentioned on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_-_Volume_Alpha):

> Minecraft - Volume Alpha is the first soundtrack released for Minecraft by C418, which features all of the songs available since Alpha made by him **plus some extras**.

C418 did the same when recording *Volume Beta* — more tracks were created than just those that appeared in the game at the time.

Answer (score 0):

What minecraft version are you running? The "newmusic" resource folder is different depending on whether or not you've run the new versions or not. In any case, this isn't an easily answerable question just due to its general nature. I can try to help to the best of my ability, nonetheless. If you haven't run the newer versions, you could simply have not downloaded the resources.

Comment: I've been running Minecraft since 1.7, mainly 1.8+.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness then I'm not sure. It could be an issue with the client software or it may just be an anomaly altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I listened to this, and ALL of these are in 2017 xbox one edition (Java) If you play the dead version of minecraft xbox you will hear ALL of these ie Flakes is in one of the free maps and others are played within the game.